# Calculate the kernel of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Calculate the kernel of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$$T(x_1,...,x_6) = (x_1-x_2+2x_4-3x_5+x_6,2x_1-x_2-x_3+3x_4-4x_5+4x_6)$$

By definition, this we have that $ker(T) = \{(x_1,...x_6) \in \mathbb{R}^6\ |$ $x_1-x_2+2x_4-3x_5+x_6=0 $ $\text{and}$  $2x_1-x_2-x_3+3x_4-4x_5+4x_6=0  \}$

How do I go about calculating this more explicitly?

---

My attempt: I see by inspection that $(1,0,1,1,1,0) \in ker(T)$, I would like to somehow extend this to a basis for the kernel.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1-x_2+2x_4-3x_5+x_6=0\\2x_1-x_2-x_3+3x_4-4x_5+4x_6=0.\end{array}\right.$$If you replace the second equation by its sum with the first one times $-2$, you get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1-x_2+2x_4-3x_5+x_6=0\\x_2-x_3-x_4+2x_5+2x_6=0.\end{array}\right.$$Now, if you replace the first equation by its sum with the second one, you get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1-x_3+x_4-x_5+3x_6=0\\x_2-x_3-x_4+2x_5+2x_6=0.\end{array}\right.$$This is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1=x_3-x_4+x_5-3x_6\\x_2=x_3+x_4-2x_5-2x_6\end{array}\right.$$and therefore$$\ker(T)=\{(a-b+c-3d,a+b-2c-2d,a,b,c,d)\mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R\}.$$